# ionic capacitor isn't generating run config for the android emulator

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm follwing the guide in this section: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android#running-with-capacitor

However, when I get to:

> 2. In Android Studio, click the Run button and then select the target simulator or device.

Which I'm getting to by issuing `npx cap open android`, I can't click 'run' because there's no run configuration. If I try to *Add Configuration* I can't select my app directory (or any directory) as the module - it just says *<no module>* in the dropdown.

Is there a step I'm missing or something that causes this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone this may benefit, in my case I had installed the Android SDK platform but not the requisite SDK tools. There is a second tab in the Android Studio > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK menu called SDK Tools. You need to make sure you also install the correct tools from there.

To get the run configuration I believe you at least need the Android SDK Build-Tools.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it, you should ignore the sections on creating a new virtual device if you have one already. In essence the issue was that my AVD was v28 and my SDK was v30 so it wasn't compatible hence no config.